# how to run perl program automatic when the perl program isn't running?

Tags: perl, shell

i have run a perl program like a deamon,
    perl check.pl &

now,i can check the perl program running state,but how to modify the shell script to running the perl program when the perl program isn't running ?

```
    a=`ps -ef | grep "perl" | grep "check" |awk '{print $2}'`
    for p in $a
    do
      echo perl
      echo $p
   done
```

Comment: you could use a cronjob to check every n minutes if your program is running and if not restart it.

but for that you should make it a real system daemon.

Daemon::Control is a perl module that helps with creating such a daemon. there are probably alternatives, but that is the one I am using for some time now.

what is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you have root/admin privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,

- *i have run a perl program like a deamon, perl check.pl &*

This, *isn't* *like a daemon*, but an simple background process. Every process has an *parent* process. The background process (like the above) has as a parent the "bash" what sends it into the bakcground, so the bash can `wait` for it's termination. The *daemon* has parent process the process called `init`, with the `PID == 1` and therefore it is watched by the `init`.

- *now,i can check the perl program running state,*

Yes, as you can check any other program's state. One comment, doing such `grep` on program names coukd have some strange side effects, like:

```
$ perl log.pl &
```

Now, grepping the output of the `ps` will lead to two, "log" processes, which one of them will be the `syslogd` process. Of course, youre in your example limited this with an another `grep` to `perl` only, but at the cost of two processes.

You can limit two processes to one, using some smarter grep argument, like

```
ps -ef | grep 'perl check'
```

the above would search with one process, the string "perl check". Unfortunately, this will find the `grep` process itself, like

```
$ perl check.pl &
$ ps -ef | grep 'perl check
  501 45063 42171   0 11:26   ttys001    0:00.00 grep perl check
  501 45002 44504   0 11:21   ttys002    0:00.02 perl check.pl
```

One nice workaround is using a sting like

```
grep '[p]erl check'
```

like

```
$ perl check.pl &
$ ps -ef | grep '[p]erl check'
  501 45002 44504   0 11:21   ttys002    0:00.02 perl check.pl
```

- *but how to modify the shell script to running the perl program when the perl program isn't running ?*

If the grepping the outout of `ps` returns nothing, you should start the script. You should check the content of your `a` (you really should give it better name as `a`, like `perlPID` or such). If the length of the argument of `-z` is zero, it returns "true", so:

```
[[ -z "$a" ]] && perl check.pl &
```

Answer (score 1):

You can leave running check to perl itself, and call it regularly via system crontab,

```
use Fcntl ':flock';
flock(DATA, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB) or die "Already running..\n";

# ...


__DATA__
```